# Do records generate overrides for inherited positional properties?

Tags: c#, c#-record-type

Consider the following record definitions:

```
public record BaseRecord(string Text)
{
    public string Text { get; init; } = Normalize(Text);

    // ...
}

public record DerivedRecord(string Text) : BaseRecord(Text)
{
    // ...
}
```

`BaseRecord` will have the normalized value for `Text`. But **does `DerivedRecord` reuse the `Test` property from `BaseRecord`, or does it generate a new one that ignores the normalized base value?**

Further: What if `BaseRecord` did not have `Text` as a positional parameter, but only as a regular property?

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after finishing writing the question, I came up with this test code.

This experiment answered my question directly, but an answer that provided more details, insight, or generally explained in more detail the way code is generated for derived records would be valuable.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var x = new DerivedRecord("text", "derived other");
        var (text, other) = x;
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        Console.WriteLine(other);
    }
}

public record BaseRecord(string Text)
{
    public string Text { get; init; } = Text.ToUpper(); 
    public string Other { get; init; } = "base other";

    // ...
}

public record DerivedRecord(string Text, string Other) : BaseRecord(Text)
{
    // ...
}
```

Running it on https://dotnetfiddle.net/ printed `"TEXT"` rather than `"text"`, which suggests to me that the base property is being used in `DerivedRecord`. Additionally, the second line said `"base other"` rather than `"derived other"`, which suggests not only that `DerivedType` even re-used the base `Other` property, but maybe also that it completely ignores the value given to the constructor as a result.

Comment: I wanted to quickly prove your words and clicked on fiddle link..  /facepalm Maybe next time you better [share](https://dotnetfiddle.net/b8NpDl) example from fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of inheritance for record types is to add additional properties to existing record types.

Consider this more simplified example:

```
public record BaseRecord(string Text);

public record DerivedRecord(string Text, string Other) : BaseRecord(Text);
```

The user expects now from `DerivedRecord` a record type with 2 properties: `Text` and `Other`.
The compiler sees that BaseRecord already has the property `Text` and only adds `Other` as another property.

If the compiler would not do this, there would be 2 properties named `Text` where the derived property would hide the base property (known as shadowing) which is definitely not a behavior you want.

Comment: That's a good intuition, but there are a ton of factors to consider concerning code generation for record types (especially with inheritance). Ultimately I don't think it's wise to assume it will behave the way we'd want or expect.